# Using parameters with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm using the linux pthreads library to try the threads features, the code below prints 5 messages on the screen for each thread, each thread waits its turn to display the message controlled using the semaphores, in Windows it works perfectly, but in linux the threads do not wait their turn, I already researched everything that is singing and I could not reach a solution to this problem. My deduction is that I'm doing something wrong with the parameter struct

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct param{
  int id;
  pthread_mutex_t lock;
  sem_t semaforo;
}valores_t;

void * olamundo(void* args){
  valores_t* p = args;
  sem_wait(&p->semaforo);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Hello from thread %d\n", p->id);
  }
  sem_post(&p->semaforo);
}

sem_t semaforo;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  /* code */

  if(sem_init(&semaforo,0,1)){//valor inicial do semaforo começa por 1
    printf("Error\n");
  }

  valores_t p[2];
  pthread_t threads[2];

    p[0].id = 1;
    p[0].semaforo = semaforo;

    p[1].id = 2;
    p[1].semaforo = semaforo;

  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    if(pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, &olamundo, &p[i]) == -1){
      printf("Error\n");
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if(pthread_join(threads[i], NULL)){
      printf("Error\n");
    }
    }
    sem_destroy (&semaforo);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you should `sem_wait` before the loop, and `sem_post` after the loop.

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: It's been a while since I've written any code that directly calls the pthreads API, but I am suspicious of the assignments, `p[0].semaforo=semaforo;` and `p[1].semaforo=semaforo;`  [The documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/semaphore.h.html) for the `semaphore_t` data type does not explicitly promise that those assignments will work.  Without any such promise, I would assume that a `semaphore_t` value might be a struct and, that copying one creates either a new, distinct semaphore, or an invalid semaphore.

Comment: generally: coding in english might make it easier for us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code on ubuntu 14.04(gcc v4.8) and it works as expected so i am gussing that it is an issue of the compiler. as the comment by *james large* suggested it could be that your compiler creates a new copy of the semaphore on copy - you can test this theory with any debugging tool to verify that the semaphore is indeed the same\different object.

but a better solution is to pass it as a pointer to assure that it is not dependent of the compiler:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct param{
    int id;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    sem_t *semaforo; //Dagan: change to a pointer to a semaphore
}valores_t;

void * olamundo(void* args){
    valores_t* p = args;
    sem_wait(*(&p->semaforo)); //Dagan: use the semaphore pointer
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        printf("Ola mundo da thread %d\n", p->id);
    }
    sem_post(*(&p->semaforo)); //Dagan: use the semaphore pointer
}

sem_t semaforo;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    /* code */

    if(sem_init(&semaforo,0,1)){//valor inicial do semaforo começa por 1
        printf("Erro ao iniciar o semaforo\n");
    }

    valores_t p[2];
    pthread_t threads[2];

    p[0].id = 1;
    p[0].semaforo = &semaforo; //Dagan: pass the address of the semaphore

    p[1].id = 2;
    p[1].semaforo = &semaforo; //Dagan: pass the address of the semaphore

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){//inicia as funcoes das threads
        if(pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, &olamundo, &p[i]) == -1){
            printf("Erro ao inicializar a thread\n");
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if(pthread_join(threads[i], NULL)){
            printf("Erro ao sincronizar a thread\n");
        }
    }
    sem_destroy (&semaforo);
    return 0;
}
```

tested and works on the same compiler - and i think it is a more secure solution
Hope this will help

Comment: thanks @Dagan! I've tested on ubuntu 17.04 with gcc 5.4.0 and work as  I expected it!